# aggreagation kind in UML

Tags: properties, aggregation, uml, class-diagram

As I read that

> aggreagation kind is a property of the association's member ends

And also

> aggregation, association and composition are features of the
>   properties, which take part in the association as associatio ends, and
>   is called AggregationKind.

Could you Please clarify the two sentences through a UML simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious that both the sentences have basically the same meaning.Generally,in many-to-many associations the association has itself two or more **Properties** as **MemberEnds**. We can describe these properties separately using a type called *aggregationkind*. This **property** in fact has an attribute aggregation of type AggregationKind.

AggregationKind is an enumeration type that specifies the literals for defining the kind of aggregation of a property *or you can simply say **AggregationKind** defines the type of aggregation with the help of following basic literals:*

- **none** Indicates that the property has no aggregation.
- **shared** Indicates that the property has a shared aggregation.
- **composite** Indicates that the property is aggregated compositely, i.e., the composite object has responsibility for the existence and storage of the composed objects (parts).

It’s this **AggregationKind** that specifies the difference between a regular Association, an Aggregation and a Composition.We can understand this with help of following diagram:
[image]

NOTE: the diagram is taken from [here](http://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/?like=1)

Some of the useful links regarding this topic:

1. http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html

   2.http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/lectures/uml/class/Aggregation.htm